# Why doesn't the json model's odata property have columns?

Tags: json, sapui5

I am creating a JSON model in UI5 from a json object. But it is missing the columns array in the JSON model. I checked the model in the console and the odata property had no columns. Check image for proof.

https://ibb.co/hLmYpZb

Hence I want to know how I can get the column to show up.

Here is my code.

```
var emptyModel = {
    "columns": []
};
this.setModel(new JSONModel(JSON.stringify(emptyModel)), "selcontent");
```

I expect column to show up in the JSON model under the odata property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSONModel` awaits a *plain object* **or** a *URL* string as the first argument.

> Either the URL where to load the JSON from or a JS object [(source)](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel)

The result of the stringified `emptyModel` is `"{"columns":[]}"` which is neither an object nor a URL.